# Do I Have a Java security-role-mapping Conflict

Tags: java, security

I have a customer service application that has various URLs.  However one URL (**adminquery**) is reserved strictly for customer service admins, not reps on the floor.  However, the entire app is only accessible when a user is in both the **user** and and **admin** group.  If someone is only in the **user** group, they cannot get to any resources.  So I am thinking I have a logical conflict somewhere in my mappings that is creating some sort of AND condition.

Can someone spot where I went wrong here?

web.xml:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/cs/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>cs</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/cs/adminquery</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

glassfish-web.xml mappings

```
<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>cs</role-name>
    <group-name>user</group-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>


<security-role-mapping>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
    <group-name>admin</group-name>
</security-role-mapping>
```